# How would one marking up Wordpress content with RDFa?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hopefully, I can write this to avoid any problems that caused a similar post to be closed.  I don't mean to invite debate or say whether or not RDFa should be handled on Wordpress in a way similar to another CMS.  I just want to see if one were going to do this, how it would be done.  In other words, do we do this in the theme?  Ideally, we need custom fields and RDF mappings for each field and for the Content type.

So, maybe this goes in the Wordpress functions.php file.  The user interface would need a way to ask the user, what property to assign to each field, e.g. if it is a name, then we might use foaf:name.  The content type itself, would correspond to a RDF type, aka Class.  I'm not sure how one would accomplish this.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that i'd implement RDF using Simple Fields: http://simple-fields.com/ to add custom fields specifically to post types.

Then i'd print the data with the correct XML syntax in the theme.

Maybe you can write some helpers in your functions.php (or similar) to avoid code duplication to print RDF information, but this is something more.